# Can skill be transferred in less time?

Tags: practice

Gaining skill in a particular field, in general, takes a lot of time.

But, many instances in Hinduism scriptures confirms that vidya can be transferred in much lesser time.

*Some of such scenarios are:*

Rituparna giving to Nala the skill in science of dies

> **And saying this, Rituparna imparted unto Nala the science (he desired). And Nala upon becoming acquainted with the science of dice,
>   Kali came out of his body, incessantly vomiting from his mouth the
>   virulent poison of Karkotaka.**

Nala giving to Rituparna the vidya related to horse riding

> **O king, with all my desires gratified, I lived happily in thy abode, in fact more happily there than in my own house. This thy horse-lore is in my keeping. If thou wishest, O king, I will make it over to thee.' Saying this, Naishadha gave unto Rituparna that science and the latter took it with the ordained rites.**

Vrihadaswa to Yudhishthira the science of dice

> **Vaisampayana continued, "King Yudhishthira then, with a glad heart, said unto Vrihadaswa, 'O illustrious one, I desire to learn the
>   science of dice from thee.' The Rishi then gave his dice-lore unto the
>   high-souled son of Pandu, and having given it unto him, that great
>   ascetic went to the sacred waters of Hayasirsha for a bath.**

My doubt is either only knowledge is transferring or skill along with knowledge is transferring in such scenarios?

Is such transfer possible in Kaliyuga?

Comment: Another example is, Valmiki awakened Kundalini power of Luv and Kush instantly which usually takes sometimes multiple births to get awaken. To activate it instatly, your Guru must be capable of doing this. Awaken kundalini power was the reason they were undefeated when they caught yagya horse.